# Use jquery-ui in portal 8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, portal, websphere-portal

I have followed this article to use jquery in websphere portal 8 and its working.
http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/portal/8.0.0/doc/en_us/PT800ACD002/dev/themeopt_jquery.html

The question I have is how do I use jquery-ui in websphere portal 8. The reason behind this question is, there are a bunch of js files and css files that are associated with jquery-ui and I am not sure if I have to declare each and every css and js file in the plugin.xml to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I would add it as a module in the profile.json file.
Here are the instructions:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Adding_new_Dojo_Modules_in_IBM_Portal_8.0
Just add the jquery file instead of a dojo file.

Documentation on the modular framework:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM WebSphere Portal Express 8 Product Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=The_module_framework_exp8&content=pdcontent

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but, I would expect you will need to declare each JS and CSS in your module.

An alternative to having to declare them individually is to pull them together into a single JS file and a single CSS file (or maybe one JS/CSS for each logical component). Then in your module you only have a limited number of files to declare. Make this a part of your build process and you should rarely have to up date your module definition to include any new files you start to use.

There are plenty of tools that compress and concatenate JS and CSS files to help automate this process.

This post is a couple years old but looks to offer lots of options to start evaluating.
http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/19/tools-for-concatenating-and-minifying-css-and-javascript-files-in-different-development-environments/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to include the jquery.js/jquery-ui.js from the head.jsp of the theme. So that the jquery/jquery ui features/components are available to all the portlets and theme modules.